# Application for NiederlassungsErlaubnis in Germany with Bluecard

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have worked with a blue card from  December 2021- (end of April 2022), and from 16th of June 2022 until now. I hold a B1 German certificate. When can I be eligible to apply for permanent residence? The law says 21 months of paid taxes and stuff but is it a problem if there is a gap ? I have a gap from 1st of May 2022 to 16th of June 2022. When can I earliest apply ?

Comment: what did you do before December 21? If your job conditions satisfied Blue Card requirements before getting a BlueCard, time before getting BluCard can be also calculated as time with BlueCard for NE.

Answer (score -3):

> […] is it a problem if there is a gap ? […]

**Yes**, there is.
§ 18c Ⅱ AufenthG reads:

> ¹[…] dem Inhaber einer Blauen Karte EU [ist] eine Niederlassungserlaubnis zu erteilen, wenn er mindestens 33 Monate eine Beschäftigung nach § 18b Absatz 2 ausgeübt hat […]

It literally says “held *one* employment”.
The German state wants to see (especially for this expedited venue you’re taking) some *firm* evidence you can *permanently* make a living.
Suppose you bounced your way from one job to the next for the past 21 months; there’s a good chance you’ll be unemployed soon.
The German state does not like seeing that.

> […] When can I be eligible to apply for permanent residence. […]

On the other hand (frictional) unemployment is a normal phenomenon.
Short-term interruptions (in total ≤ 3 months) are therefore harmless.
Presuming you remain employed, you should be eligible after October 15.

> […] When can I earliest apply ?

On October 16.
You need to present *hard* facts.
It could be argued that an application on September 16 is acceptable, because of the statutory notice period, yet this dismisses the fact that you can be fired without notice for gross misconduct (e. g. stealing company property).

Comment: Don't agree at all with this answer. It could also be "held an employment". It is firm evidence enough if you have an unbefristet contract, without Probezeit . Bouncing jobs has no significance, you do not speak for the German state. And the application date is not October 15, you can apply even today if you wanted to! But it wont be processed before October 15.

Comment: @quantum These considerations were taken from the [2009 edition of the AufenthG-AVV](https://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_26102009_MI31284060.htm); I could not find an updated version. There it does contain explicit statements “an application is to be rejected if all requirements are not yet fulfilled” (minimum employment period) and “necessary employment must have been with a single employer.” It is all there. I did not make up these considerations by myself. “Held _an_ employment” still means only one employment, not several employments (_Beschäftigungen_, plural).

Comment: @mudur2023 What’s the status? Could you provide some updated information?